# How to handle Facebook App ID changes in Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

Changing the `App ID` changes the `uid`. So if a user that has signed up with Facebook tries to log in after App ID has changed she won't be recognized as the old user and a new account will be created for her.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Curious, but why is the App ID changing? Are you creating a new FB app and trying to bring existing users over to it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try comparing other data you've gathered to try and match them (e.g. email address, phone number...) but this would probably have caveats and/or security implications.

What would probably be safer if the app is still operated by the same entity is the Business Mapping API which looks like it can map user ids across apps owned by the same business:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

The cross-promotion docs might have some relevant info for you too.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/bestpractice/cross-promotion

There's some introductory text in the API 1 -> 2 upgrade guide which also links to the above pages:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

I'm afraid I haven't used these APIs though, as I haven't had to worry about uids across apps.